# kotlin multiplatform + react

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, core-js

I have a project on kotlin multiplatform and want to use kotlin react for that. Added dependencies to build.gradle:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-react:16.13.0-pre.94-kotlin-1.3.70")
implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-react-dom:16.13.0-pre.94-kotlin-1.3.70")
implementation(npm("react", "16.13.1"))
implementation(npm("react-dom", "16.13.1"))
```

however i got a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

in kotlin-react-dom.js and kotlin-react.js

i found that it because of core-js, which is not provided. How can i add it to my project with gradle?

[image]

my build.gradle https://pastebin.com/pGi1Au5L

Comment: I failed to reproduce your problem with a dummy project. Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: can`t add link to the project, but  can attach build.gradle file https://pastebin.com/pGi1Au5L

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. [Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/issues/36) said that you need to do `npm i` in a folder with package.json. But the problem is that my package.json is generated by Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was because of old project, I started a new one.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did you write a new ```build.gradle```? If you did, can you share it? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I created a new project in idea with newest version of kotlin and gradle. Then I started migrate my old project to new one